# Websocket -- PHP Push Data

Tags: php, javascript, websocket

I'm running this loop on the server side:

```
while (true) {
    $changed = $this->sockets;
    socket_select($changed, $write = NULL, $except = NULL, NULL);
    foreach($changed AS $socket) {
            if($socket == $this->master) {
                    $client = socket_accept($this->master);
                    if($client < 0) {
                            echo "socket_accept failed";
                            continue;
                    } else {
                            $this->connect($client);
                    }
            } else {
                    $bytes = @socket_recv($socket, $buffer, 2048, 0);
                    if($bytes == 0) {
                            $this->close($socket);
                    } else {
                            $user = $this->get_user_by_socket($socket);
                            if(!$user->handshake) {
                                    $this->do_handshake($user, $buffer);
                            } else {
                                    $this->process($user, $buffer);
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

Basically it waits for anything to be changed within the sockets before performing any actions that can be sent to all clients, or just individual clients. What I would like to do is be able to push data to clients after a period of inactivity...say like a countdown timer in a game. So after 5 seconds if there has been no action from a user, automatically send an action for that user. How would I go about that? I've tried to have a last_update with the time() stored in it then check the math, but anything that I put within the while(true) loop only gets run when there is a change in the sockets, which comes from the user end...

I guess I'm just super lost.  :)

Thanks!

Comment: What do u want us to answer ?!?!?

Comment: I think the OP wants to know, how to go about performing the actions laid out in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a non-blocking flag for your socket_recv() function. Otherwise it will just sit on this line until a minimum number of bytes have been received.

Perhaps

```
$bytes = socket_recv($socket, $buffer, 2048, MSG_DONTWAIT);
```

Comment: Ok...so I throw that flag in there then I can just run a function at the end of the while(true) loop?

Comment: Large problem...when I throw the MSG_DONTWAIT flag in there, the client is disconnected immediately after connecting...very bad...  :)

Comment: Look carefully at your code. You are checking if no bytes were received, then you explicitly close the connection. You obviously won't get getting bytes on every iteration since you are using a non-blocking function.